# Cannot GET / error,

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I'm trying to handle routing in external files however I'm seeing a 'Cannot Get /' error. I'm not sure what am I doing wrong, can someone please explain?

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const routes = require('./router/api/routes')


const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use('/api/routes', routes)



const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port,() => console.log(`server started on port ${port}`))
```

routes.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('../../website.html')
})

module.exports=router;
```

Comment: You have no routes defined for " / ", so you have to point the url to '/api/routes in the browser'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> app.use('/api/routes', routes)
> ```

You bound your routes to `/api/routes` so `/` is `/api/routes/`.

Comment: Oh ok makes sense, I've changed it to app.use('/', routes) however now I am getting this error:TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
    at ServerResponse.sendFile

Comment: @shak.s — That's an entirely unrelated problem.